# js Post on friends facebook wall with taggable_friend ID

Tags: javascript, facebook

first I get all users friends

```
FB.login(function(response){
        console.log(response);

        FB.api(
            "/me/taggable_friends?fields=name,id,picture.width(100).height(100)",
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    $('#usersList').find('li').remove();
                    response.data.forEach(function(a, b){
                        console.log(a, b);
                        $('#usersList').append('<li class="users__item jsUser" data-fb-name="'+ a.name+'" data-fb-id="'+ a.id+'">'+
                        '<a class="users__link">'+
                        '<img src="'+ a.picture.data.url+'" height="63" width="64" alt="" class="users__pic">'+
                        '</a>'+
                        '</li>');
                    });
                    bindJsUser();
                }
            }
        );



    }, {scope: 'public_profile,user_friends'});
```

ID of every friend loks like gahdfashjdfg234234137ryuhdsfius43534523wdfwef43r435, and I can't post on wall with that ID

```
var user = $('#usersList').find('li.active');
    if(!user){
        return;
    }
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        to: user.attr('data-fb-id'), // <-- PROBLEM
        link: 'http://snow.sa-wd.ru',
        picture: 'http://snow.sa-wd.ru/images/preview-greeting.webp',
        name: 'test',
        caption: 'Submit to friend',
        description: 'Using Dialogs for posting to friends timeline.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response['post_id']);
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

error:

API Error Code: 100
    API Error Description: Invalid parameter
    Error Message: AaIIMETTji_8-        m19fUI***yc*********GUTQg does not    resolve to a valid user ID

Comment: @KollleY User ID's you're getting are not correct. User Id in Facebook are numeric only.

Comment: I know but can't get real user ID from "taggable_friends"

Comment: @KollleY I just checked out the Docs they updated the ID field you're getting correct tagging tokens in ID. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends

What are you actually trying to do? because in the docs it states you can't publish anything you can only tag them in a story.

Comment: I want to post message on wall

Comment: I don't think that endpoint returns tokens for posting on someone else's wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed dialog is deprecated and should not be used anymore. And the docs say "**The ID must be a friend who also uses your app.**" - that goes for the "to" parameter. So if you really still want to use the feed dialog, just **use `/me/friends` to get all the friends who authorized your App** and use one of the IDs for the "to" parameter.

Btw, you are not allowed to use `taggable_friends` for anything else than tagging/mentioning. That´s why you only get "tagging tokens", not User IDs.

You would never get it approved for what you want to achieve:

> Use of this edge must be reviewed by Facebook before it can be called on behalf of people who use your app.

That being said, it´s bad practice to post on the wall of a friend, even with the deprecated feed dialog. It always looks like spam. **That´s why it´s not possible to post to friends who did not authorize your App.**

Comment: How can I post something on friends wall? What should I do?
friends edge return only count of my friends

Comment: i´ve added some more information and highlighted the most important parts.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand, what should I do for posting?
Of course, /friends returns only count, and I can't get something else from this edge

Comment: it´s all in the first paragraph. use /me/friends to get the IDs for the "to" parameter.

Comment: So, first I should find some way to invite users to my application?

Comment: for example, yes. but you should read this before trying something: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app